# Как сделать флаг, просмотрена ли страница?

Tags: алгоритм

Идея.
Есть страница:

```
Ссылка 1
Ссылка 2
```

В течение жизненного цикла сайта я добавляю к нему кое-какое содержимое:

```
Ссылка 1
Ссылка 2
(Новое!) Ссылка 3
```

Пользователь, войдя на сайт, видит эту надпись (Новое!), понимает, что тут что-то новое, заходит, читает, затем возвращается обратно и видит:

```
Ссылка 1
Ссылка 2
Ссылка 3
```

Надеюсь объяснил потребность понятно. Теперь вопрос: как это реализовать алгоритмически? Мне на ум приходит только идея для каждого зарегистрированного пользователя завести флаг *isViewed*, но что-то мне подсказывает, что это не самый оптимальный вариант.

P.S. Сайт в интрасети, пользователи всегда авторизованы.

Comment: думаю по другому никак

Comment: Можно сделать одну таблицу со всеми страницами, и смежную таблицу где many-to-many будут пользователи-страницы.

Comment: Можно было бы фиксировать у пользователя дату последнего перехода на "Новое" и у ссылок дату создания. Но к сожалению поможет только если ссылка одна, как только он по ней перейдет другие "новое" то же погаснут... А ссылок много планируется и есть ли база данных где это фиксировать и если да, то какая ?

Comment: @Mike ссылок много, база ms sql. Для каждого пользователя нужно своё состояние ссылки, если один посмотрел, это не значит, что все посмотрели

Comment: Тогда другого выхода кроме как в отдельной таблице фиксировать id-ссылки id-пользователя нет. Если другой информации (типа голосования за ссылки, лайков/дизлайков) хранить не надо, то сам факт наличия записи считать как "просмотрено".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вообще-то можно куку сделать специальную. JS-ом ставить оформление новой ссылки, если нет куки соответствующей, а при посещении заданного урла ее на клиенте записывать.

Но я бы на твоем месте об интерфейсе задумался. Если есть список новостей каких-то, то пусть он показывает самые новые сверху. А то кнопа NEW возле ссылок это уже не комильфо давно.

Comment: Согласно ТЗ документы должны быть отсортированы по алфавиту, а если в них происходят изменения или добавляются новые, должна появляться такая отметка

Comment: @сергейтамбовцев Ну ТЗ значит ТЗ :) Наверно лучше действительно сделать таблицу соответствий "Пользователи - Страницы" в БД. И страницам флаг добавить, смотреть ли для них такие соответствия, а то все страницы будут "новыми" до первого посещения. Хотя, может так и надо.

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать воспользоваться псевдоклассом CSS :visited

Например:

```
a:link {
    color: #0000d0; /* Цвет ссылок */
}

a:visited {
    color: #900060; /* Цвет посещенных ссылок */
}
```